# A way to make the [apply + lambda + loc] efficient

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, google-colaboratory

The dataframe(contains data on the 2016 elections), loaded in pandas from a .csv has the following structure:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   county  candidate  votes  ...
0  Ada     Trump      10000  ...
1  Ada     Clinton    900    ... 
2  Adams   Trump      12345  ...
.
.
n  Total   ...        ...    ...
```

The idea would be to calculate the first X counties with the highest percentage of votes in favor of candidate X (removing Totals)

For example suppose we want *100 counties*, and the candidate is *Trump*, the operation to be carried out is: `100 * sum of votes for Trump / total votes`

I have implemented the following code, getting correct results:

```
In [3]: (df.groupby(by="county")
           .apply(lambda x: 100 * x.loc[(x.candidate == "Trump") 
                  & (~x.county == "Total"), "votes"].sum() / x.votes.sum())
           .nlargest(100) 
           .reset_index(name='percentage'))
Out[3]: 
   county   percentage
0  Hayes    91.82
1  WALLACE  90.35
2  Arthur   89.37
.
.
99 GRANT    79.10
```

Using `%%time` i realized that it is quite slow:

```
Out[3]: 
CPU times: user 964 ms, sys: 24 ms, total: 988 ms
Wall time: 943 ms
```

Is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to amend your codes to use only vectorized operations to speed up the process, like below:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df.county != "Total")]     # exclude the Total row(s)

df2 = 100 * df1.groupby(['county', 'candidate'])['votes'].sum() / df1.groupby('county')['votes'].sum()     # calculate percentage for each candidate

df3 = df2.nlargest(100).reset_index(name='percentage')   # get the largest 100

df3.loc[df3.candidate == "Trump"]        # Finally, filter by candidate
```

### Edit:

If you want the top 100 counties with the highest percentages, you can slightly change the codes below:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df.county != "Total")]     # exclude the Total row(s)

df2 = 100 * df1.groupby(['county', 'candidate'])['votes'].sum() / df1.groupby('county')['votes'].sum()     # calculate percentage for each candidate

df3a = df2.reset_index(name='percentage')   # get the percentage

df3a.loc[df3a.candidate == "Trump"].nlargest(100, 'percentage')       # Finally, filter by candidate and get the top 100 counties with highest percentages for the candidate
```

Comment: this solution is much faster, in this way I have everything ready, if I finally wanted to filter for another candidate it would be enough for me to duplicate the last statement, love it

Comment: @anas  See my edit which calculates the top 100 counties with the highest percentages.  See whether this should fit better your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

- Supposing you **don't have** a 'Total' row with the sum of all votes:

```
(df[df['candidate'] == 'Trump'].groupby(['county']).sum()/df['votes'].sum()*100).nlargest(100, 'votes')
```

- Supposing you **have** a 'Total' row with the sum of all votes:

```
(df[df['candidate'] == 'Trump'].groupby(['county']).sum()/df.loc[df['candidate'] != 'Total', 'votes'].sum()*100).nlargest(100, 'votes')
```

I could not test it because I don`t have the data but it doesn't use any `apply` which **could** increase the performance

for the rename of the columns you can use `.rename(columns={'votes':'percentage'})` at the end

Comment: I fixed your code to work: `(df[df['candidate'] == "Trump" & df['county'] != "Total")].groupby(['county']).sum() / df.groupby(['county']).sum() * 100).nlargest(100, 'votes')` it goes much faster, but are the two groupbys written like that a good practice?

Comment: sure! ```groupby``` is a vectorized operation which is much faster but you have to make sure the shape of both are always the same